# EXISTS / NOT EXISTS in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

- Project (idProject, nameProject)
- Operator(idOperator, nameOperator)
- Project_Operator (idProject, idOperator, begindate, enddate)

I want the list of operators that they never been in a project for the last 7 months

```
SELECT I.* 
FROM Operator I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Project_Operator 
                  WHERE SYSDATE-begindate < 7 
                    AND I.numOperator = numOperator);
```

I want to know if this is correct or not

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know if this is correct or not

Comment: Does it return the correct result?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I added the `oracle` tag because `sysdate` suggests Oracle.

Comment: I'm just having some problems understanding EXISTS/NOT EXISTS.. It works but I don't know if that means it's correct or not

Answer (score 1):

You are sort of close, but the difference between dates is in days, not months, and the logic is backwards:

```
SELECT I.* 
FROM Operator i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Project_Operator  po
                  WHERE po.begindate > add_months(sysdate, -7) AND
                        I.numOperator = po.numOperator
                );
```

That is, there is no project ("`not exists1`") that began in the last seven months (`po.begindate > add_months(sysdate, -7)`).